# Did 12 Michael Jackson fans die by suicide in wake of his death?

Tags: mortality

Several articles from celebrity news sites, posted in June of 2009, posted claims that around 12 Michael Jackson fans had taken their own life.  These sources all nearly say the exact same thing: [[1]](http://www.gigwise.com/news/51468/12-Michael-Jackson-Fans-%27Commit-Suicide%27-In-Wake-Of-His-Death)[[2]](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/2508569/Jackos-fans-commit-suicide.html)

Up to 12 heartbroken followers of the star have taken their lives – including one Brit — said the MJJcommunity website.

> The startling claim came as it was revealed a Jackson lookalike in Russia cut his wrists after the star’s death was announced.
>
> Gary Taylor, who runs MJJcommunity.com, said: "I know there has been
> an increase, I now believe the figure is 12. I believe there may have
> been one Briton who has taken their life.

Only one man has ever been named as one of the 12 who died by suicide is the Jackson lookalike mentioned in the article itself; but I can't find any other sources online that would indicate 12 others actually took their own lives in light of Jackson's passing.

Did 12 Michael Jackson fans die by suicide in wake of his death?

Comment: Let's limit this to factual statements, as it stands it asks us to prove a negative: we'd need to check literally every suicide for weeks after Jackson's death to determine whether this is true or not.